# How can WebAssembly run on any machine?

Tags: assembly, browser, webassembly

Have seen a couple of WebAssembly (Wasm) presentation lately. I get it that Wasm is a compilation target which **statically typed** languages like C/C++ can compile to. The browser then can run the Wasm code and somehow transform this into the machine code of its respective machine. Like this:

[image: Wasm WebAssembly]

### Question:

How is the browser able to transform Wasm into appropriate machine code?

Comment: With a JIT compiler.  I'm not familiar with webassembly in detail, but I assume it's something like LLVM-IR.

A quick google turned up https://idea.popcount.org/2013-07-24-ir-is-better-than-assembly/ which has some reasonable looking diagrams and code snippets describing LLVM-IR.  I think all of that would apply equally to webassembly.  (This is kind of an answer, but it's totally based on assumptions so only posting a comment.)

Comment: How exactly is way too broad to answer. It may help to explain why you're asking this question given that compilers can transform C/C++ code into machine code.

Comment: Yea removed the exactly part, just want an general overview though. The browser has a JIT compiler for this purpose?

Comment: Browsers that want to support wasm would need a JIT compiler for it, yes.  Or less usefully, an interpreter, but that would probably defeat the performance purpose vs. just using an efficient JS JIT engine like v8 for plain JS code.

Comment: webassembly can't run on **any** machine. Only where web browser supporting webassembly is available. In this regard the webassembly is same as any other interpreted programming language (although its form is binary, so rather than "programming language" it is more like intermediate object file, produced by compilers of some other programming language, like C++ or JS, but from the "browser" point of view that's completely irrelevant, it simply has something to interpret or compile with JIT and execute and so it will do that). = i.e. the heavy lifting (providing compiler) is on browser vendor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers have both interpreters and JIT compilers for JavaScript. These are typically quite complex, with the browser having to do a lot of ‘work’ to create an optimised JITed code for the machine to execute.

With webassembly it really isn’t much different. Browsers still have to JIT the code. However, here the job is much simpler. The WebAssembly instruction set was selected to make this task relatively simple. Despite his, browsers still have ‘tiered’ compilation for WebAssembly modules.

If you want the specifics, your best bet is to look at the sourcecode for a browser!